# Rust lifetime and calling member function

Tags: rust

I have a question about lifetime of varable in Rust programming language.

`createTest` function creates and returns r-value reference. and when it returns a reference, `testValue` is destroyed. But test.print() doesn't lead to crash. Why?

(Is Test::print function called as static function?)

**Code**

```rust
struct Test;                                                         
impl Drop for Test {                                                       
  fn drop (&mut self) {                                                    
    println("Dropped.");                                                   
  }                                                                        
}                                                                          

impl Test {                                                                
  fn print(&self) { println!("Print!"); }                                  
}                                                                          

fn createTest() -> &Test {                                                 
  let testValue = &Test;                                                   
  return testValue;                                                        
}                                                                          

fn main() {                                                                
  let test = createTest();                                             
  test.print();                                                            
  println("Test");                                                         
}
```

**Result**

```
Dropped.
Print!
Test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the code compiles is because the use of a unit struct (i.e. no fields), is basically equivalent to:

```rust
 struct Test;

 static TestStatic: Test = Test;

 fn createTest() -> &Test {
      &TestStatic
 }
```

And so the `&TestStatic` expression has type `&'static Test`. *Every* lifetime is a sub-lifetime of `'static`, including the implicit anonymous one for the `-> &Test`, so you're allowed to return a `'static` in it's place.

This behaviour is covered by two bugs:

- [8309](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/8309)
- [10800](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/10800)

---

That said, it is *very* strange that `Drop` runs like that, so thank you for filing [11681](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/11681).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug to me. A simple extension of your example does not compile with absolutely natural error message:

```rust
struct Test {
    x: int
}

impl Drop for Test {
  fn drop (&mut self) {
    println("Dropped.");
  }
}

impl Test {
  fn print(&self) { println!("Print: {}", self.x); }
}

fn createTest() -> &Test {
  let testValue = &Test{ x: 10 };
  testValue
}

fn main() {
  let test = createTest();
  test.print();
  println("Test");
}
```

Error message:

```
main.rs:16:19: 16:24 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
main.rs:16   let testValue = &Test{ x: 10 };
                             ^~~~~
main.rs:15:26: 18:2 note: reference must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 15:25...
main.rs:15 fn createTest() -> &Test {
main.rs:16   let testValue = &Test{ x: 10 };
main.rs:17   testValue
main.rs:18 }
main.rs:15:26: 18:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 15:25
main.rs:15 fn createTest() -> &Test {
main.rs:16   let testValue = &Test{ x: 10 };
main.rs:17   testValue
main.rs:18 }
```

BTW, you don't have to write `return` when you want to return something from a function unless it is an early return (e.g. from inside a loop). Just leave out semicolon at the last statement.